# Incomplete type error (E0409, E0070, E0515)

Tags: c++, tuples, incomplete-type

In my code `Main.cpp` I have the following shown below. The issue I am running into us with `tuple<int, int, int>`
I keep getting these three errors

`function "sPA" returns incomplete type "trie"`, `incomplete type is not allowed`, and
`cannot convert to incomplete class "trie"`

What am I doing wrong here to make this error?

```
 // Main.cpp
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

 typedef pair<int, int> int_pair;
 typedef tuple<int, int, int> trie;



 int_pair sum_and_product(int a, int b) {
     return int_pair(a + b, a * b);
 }

 trie sPA(int a, int b, int c) {
     trie t{ a + b + c,a * b * c,((a + b + c) / 3) };
     return t;
 } 

 void consuming_templates() {
     int a = 2, b = 3, c = 4;
     auto results = sum_and_product(a,b);
     cout << "sum = " << results.first << "|product = " << results.second << endl;
     auto r2 = sPA(a, b, c);
 }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    consuming_templates();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you have includes in your code? please include them also here

Comment: you have to include `<tuple>` and I believe `pair` is in `<util>`

Comment: @idclev463035818 `<utility>`*

Comment: Note: quite often library headers will contain a forward declaration of a type rather than include the header for a type because the forward declaration is a lot faster to compile than the header most users won't need. This leads to errors like this if you need more than a reference to the and do not include the correct header.

Comment: ... and I think thats why your `typedef`s dont cause an error

Comment: Disagree with the close votes btw,  it was a lack of knowledge and not a typo, and this question might be useful to others who search the same error message

Comment: @M.M is there a way I can make it not close if other people vote it to be closed?

Comment: If you accept your answer then it will prevent the question from being closed

Comment: I shall in 2 days since it says I can in 2 days @M.M

Comment: OK, you should be able to mark the answer (not the question) as "community wiki" (this is normal etiquette for when writing up answers that other people posted in comments, which they're not really meant to do). Although I'm not sure whether or not that will bypass the 2 day accept time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

idclev 463035818 and M.M has posted the comment to answer my question

You need to do `#include <tuple>` and `#include <utility>`

Comment: My bad, I did not have any errors without `<utility>` so I thought it was just `<tuple>`, since it ran fine without any `tuple`

Comment: Standard headers might include other standard headers but are not required to